# Draw Pin like MKPinAnnotation View Pin in MKMapVIew

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I Want  to draw a Pin programatically like MKPinAnnotationView Pin instead of using a Pin image. If anyone have idea please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this in

> -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
>   (id )annotation

```
if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"PinId1";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                   initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin1"] autorelease];

        //pinView= [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin1"];

        //pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; 
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;

        [pinView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user.png"]];

    }
```